# Blank screen on my HP elitebook revolve 810

Tags: windows-10, hp-elitebook, capslock, blank-screen

My HP elitebook revolve 810 was working perfectly untill today when after starting the screen was blank and the Capslock was blinking continuously ,the f12 button is also lighting and the fan is working.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Take the computer to be serviced by a professional.

Comment: Can you boot into BIOS? Can you boot from USB? What testing have you done? See https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/troubleshooting/hp-elitebook-revolve-810-g1-tablet/5298038